# sql server 2016 basic select issue

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016-express

I have basic database table with some rows. see the queries below. 
first query selects a record from the database.. you see the result. that result is not the same as the other two result. yet I am retrieving the same record from the table using the different columns/methods. 
correct record is the second and 3rd select queries.

PWTransferID is the primary key. PWtransfernumber is non clustered index/Unique

I am really confused and have never seen a problem like this. can anybody shed some light on this for me. almost like the database is broken some where.

[image]

Comment: Is that just a typo in the first query? Should 227 be 277?

Comment: @MaxSzczurek Sharp eyes!

Comment: Added as an answer - thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that just a typo in the first query? Should 227 be 277?

Comment: lol, stupid me. long day. thanks